# If $A\subset\{1,11,21,31,...,541,551\}$ such that $\forall x,y\in A: x+y\ne 552$, then $|A|\le28$

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> Let $A\subset\{1,11,21,31,...,541,551\}$ such that no two elements of $A$ add up to $552$. Then show that $A$ cannot have more than $28$ elements.

Let $S=\{1,11,21,31,...,541,551\}$, whence $|S|=56$. Then surely $A\le56$, but how come $A\le\frac{56}{2}$ because of the 2nd restriction in the question? Any hint will be great. Also, is there an equivalent combinatorial presentation of the problem?

Generalising, if $A\subset\{a,a+d,a+2d,...,a+nd\}$ where $a,n,d$ are real numbers and no two elements of $A$ add up to $a+nd+1$, then does $|A|\le\frac{n+1}{2}$ hold?

**EDIT.**

After browsing some books I found that this particular property of a set has a name. The formal definition goes as,

> A set $S$ of integers is called *sum-free* if $x+y\ne S$ for every $x,y\in S$ ($x,y$ are not necessarily distinct here).

There was this particular exercise in applications of the *Pigeonhole principle* asking how big a sum-free subset of $\{1,2,...,2n+1\}$ could be, but there was no mention for a general arithmetic progression of the elements. The answer to this question was $n+1$, where the hint given was about the same as the answer already posted here. So I suppose my initial idea of generalising was wrong.

Comment: If you split this set into $56$ pairs, the sum of each is $552$, then you can take a single element from each pair, hence $|A|\leq56/2=28$.

Comment: I think the argument just requires some symmetry argument like $551 = 552 - 1$ So your $a$ is not random

Comment: If $S=a+nd+a$, your inequality hold.

Comment: @barakmanos Could you elaborate a bit as an answer?

Comment: Split it into $\{(1,551),(11,541),(21,531),\dots,(271,281)\}$, then take one element from each pair. BTW, the answer by @JimmyR. uses a similar argument, which I think is equally good (and possibly even clearer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have that $\frac{1+551}2=276$ and hence you can split $S$ in two sets with $28$ elements each, as follows: $$S_1=\{1,11,\dots,271\}, \quad S_2=\{281,282,\dots,551\}$$ with $28$ elements each. Sort $S_1$ in ascending order and $S_2$ in descending and observe that $$s_1(j)+s_2(j)=552$$ for $j=1,2,\dots,28$. Now, if $A$ has $29$ elements or more, you know that there exists $1\le j\le 28$ such that $$s_1(j),s_2(j)\in A$$

Comment: Am I the only person finding it strange that the the phrase "pigeon-hole principle" is missing in this answer as well as in other comments?

Comment: @PVanchinathan I think everybody thought that someone else would mention it since it is as clear as it gets. And in the end, at equilibrium, nobody did! So, no its not strange.

Comment: Thank you, but what is $S_1(j),S_2(j)$ actually? e.g. is $S_1(1)=\{1\},S_1(2)=\{1,11\},...$ etc?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Sorry for the bad notation: $S_1(1)=1, S_1(2)=11, S_1(3)=21$. I corrected it to lower case because they denote elements and not sets. Now in $S_2$, I want them reversed, so $s_2(1)=551,s_2(2)=541$ etc. Sorry for the confusion. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, it is clear.

Comment: Can you say something about the general case?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Let $a=2,d=2$ and $n=10$. Then in $A=\{2,4,6,\dots, 22\}$ no two elements add up to $23$. So, no, I do not think I can generalize it, because I need to impose conditions on $a$ and $d$ etc.

Comment: Very sorry, but I'm struggling to grasp the contradiction in the last sentence.

Comment: If for some j, both s_1 (j) and s_2 (j) are in A, then their sum equals 552. So contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

consider sets $$(1,551),(11,541),...,(271,281)$$

now for$$x+y\neq 552$$ max $27$ can be selected because by pp out of $28$ one atleast one pair would break the condition